# Excel equivalent Google Docs function to "query()" custom VBA function

Tags: excel

I am transitioning from Google Docs to Excel and running int oproblems with equilivent function: specifically the Google Docs: Query()

From googleing around I know that there is no Query in Excel and I have started to make a VBA function to do the same thing but running into trouble

The original Google Docs query 
    =QUERY('GP Referrals 2012-2013'!A15:Z ; "SELECT A, Z WHERE J = 'WH' ORDER BY Z DESC LIMIT 9", 0)

A is a string, Z is a number and J is one of three possible strings. I run this three times with different values in J.

Is there way to do this in Excel. I have a second sheet setup to get put the results of this in.

I have a function started but I am a but stuck as to how to get to the next step. Any help is a appreciated.

```
Function getTopGPs(clinic As String) As Integer
    Dim activeSheet As Object
    Set activeSheet = Worksheets(1)

    Dim rawRange As Object
    Set rawRange = activeSheet.Range("A15:Z65536")

    // How can I go from here?
```

End Function

Comment: Check out the data connection capability via `From Other Sources`->`From Microsoft Query` on the `Data` tab of the ribbon. The idea is to do a query on a named table in the worksheet by creation a data connection with the worksheet. You can get an idea of the VBA needed by recording the manual steps with the macro recorder.

Comment: PS: See an explanation of manually using the query tool **[here](http://superuser.com/questions/597629/refering-certain-rows-in-other-sheets-based-on-a-particular-condition)**.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @chuff's approach, give your data array labels (I chose `A`>`Z` from A14:Z14) and name the array (A14:Zn) - I chose `GParry`.

DATA > Get External Data  - From Other Sources, From Microsoft Query, Databases, Excel Files*, OK. Select your workbook name, OK, Table: GParry, Add, Close.

In the list under GParry, double-click on A, J and Z in turn, then click on the <kbd>SQL</kbd> button. In SQL statement: change `SELECT` to `SELECT TOP 9` and append:

```
WHERE J = 'WH'  
ORDER BY Z DESC
```

OK, OK.

If you want the results back into Excel just select the extract (top left), Edit, Copy and Paste where it suits you.